# Box with tabbed navigation using semantic markup structure?

Tags: jquery, html, css, semantic-markup

I'm trying to create an info box with tabs for switching the content of the box, like this: http://www.cssnewbie.com/build-a-tabbed-box-with-css-and-jquery/

Easy peasy with some CSS and jQuery right? The problem is I'm trying to figure out a way to do it with semantic markup, so that when CSS/JS are disabled, it just shows the headings with their content in the correct order. All of the examples I've seen do something like this:

```
<div id="box-nav">
    <ul>
        <li>Content head 1</li>
        <li>Content head 2</li>
        <li>Content head 3</li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div id="box-content">
    <div id="content-1">
        <p>Blah 1. </p>
    </div>
    <div id="content-2">
        <p>Blah 2. </p>
    </div>
    <div id="content-3">
        <p>Blah 3. </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

which makes it pretty easy to build by separating the headings and their content, but I want to make one using this markup:

```
<div id="content-1">
    <h2>Content head 1</h2>
    <p>Blah 1. </p>
</div>
<div id="content-2">
    <h2>Content head 2</h2>
    <p>Blah 2. </p>
</div>
<div id="content-3">
    <h2>Content head 3</h2>
    <p>Blah 3. </p>
</div>
```

so that it degrades gracefully as plain HTML, but I can't quite figure it out without using jQuery to re-arrange the markup.

Anyone know a clean way of doing this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### I have a clean, purecss and semantical solution for you

I use `dl` element instead heading elements. I think it is acceptable result.

- [basic functional demo on dabblet.com](http://dabblet.com/gist/2881519)
  [image: purecss tab]
- [decoration for purecss tab interface](http://dabblet.com/gist/2881538)
  [image: purecss tab]

In my solution `dl` element is used for semantical tabs:

> Definition lists, created using the DL element, generally consist of a series of term/definition pairs (although definition lists may have other applications). Thus, when advertising a product, one might use a definition list:

**markup** like this:

```
<div id="wrap">
    <dl>
        <dt id="ft"><a href="#tab1">TAB 1</a></dt>
            <dd id="tab1">tab1 content</dd>
        <dt id="st"><a href="#tab2">TAB 2</a></dt>
            <dd id="tab2">tab2 content</dd>
        <dt id="tt"><a href="#tab3">TAB 3</a></dt>
            <dd id="tab3">tab3 content</dd>
    </dl>
</div>
```

**Visual appearance** will be so:
[image: dl element]

For creating tab interface from this markup use this **`CSS`:**

```
#wrap, dt {
    position: absolute;
}

dl {
    overflow: hidden;
}

dt {
    bottom: 100%;
}

dd, dl {
    width: 640px;
    height: 400px;
}

#st {
    left: 92px;
}
#tt {
    left: 184px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this was the best solution overall.

Comment: @VladimirStarkov - could you explain how this actually works? I don't get how the tabs are switching content when they are clicked without any attached javascript. I see _that_ it works but the _how_ eludes me.

Comment: I got how it works. Content is stacked vertically and when you click on a tab, you're effectively linking to an anchor and using the built-in feature which scrolls linked anchors toward the top of the page. The positioning does the rest. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do Tabs with css only using the target pseudo class to hide divs

[Target class](http://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/target)

Comment: Thanks, this is useful to know but I eventually went with Vladimir's solution.